# Send list of IDs in Yesod route

Tags: haskell, url-routing, yesod

I want to have a route in my Yesod app that accepts a list of IDs

From [this page](https://www.yesodweb.com/book/routing-and-handlers#routing-and-handlers_arguments) it looks like you can use * in your route to accept a list but when I attempted it

```
/api/user/#UserId      UserR  GET DELETE
/api/users/display/*UserIds  DisplayR GET
```

I got the error

```
Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘UserIds’
Perhaps you meant one of these:
  ‘UserId’ (imported from Import.NoFoundation),
```

How would I accept a list of UserId in a route?

Comment: IIRC, it has to be `UserId` not `UserIds`.

Comment: @Sibi Changing it to UserId gives the error "No instance for (PathMultiPiece UserId) arising from a use of ‘toPathMultiPiece’"

Comment: @Qwertie, sounds like a different question then ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The route needs to be

```
/api/users/display/*[UserId]  DisplayR GET
```

And then the Handler needs to take the input type [UserId]